# Is there a way to make your own conductive thread for wearable electronics?

Tags: conductive, thread, soldering

I am a poor student, was wondering if anyone has any home-brew recipes for making conductive thread for use in wearable electronics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you could use some really low gauge wire, but I can't imagine that would save you any money.

150 yards of conductive thread is only $20 at sparkfun.

Comment: oh wow, I thought it was way more expensive than that.  Can you solder to it?

Comment: Most conductive threads can not be soldered to. Instead connections are made by tying them to components. Instead you sew the thread around the components to make a connection. See this instructable for the general idea: http://www.instructables.com/id/STN40TRFMMCYRFD

Comment: I just came across another method that claims to work really well, where you get metal beads (at a bead / craft store) and crimp them to the thread. Then solder the bead. Found here: http://www.kobakant.at/DIY/?p=1720

Answer (score 6):

Instructables has a [post](http://www.instructables.com/id/How%5Fto%5Fmake%5Fconductive%5Fthread/) on how to create conductive thread using very fine wire and thread, that combined together to create a strong, low resistance thread.

The principle idea is that you spin the the thread and the fibre together. As Andrew Parnell said, 150 yards of conductive thread is only $20 at sparkfun.

Cheers,

Marcus

Answer (score 3):

while it's not so much about making conductive thread, here is a good post talking about the different types of commercially available conductive thread.  Gives a good run down of various comparisons, where to buy and what they cost.  hope this helps!
http://www.fashioningtech.com/page/conductive-thread